# Angular Typescript error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../util/packages/core/src'

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular workspace is as follows:

```
├── projects
    ├── main\src\app
    └── util\packages\core\src
```

main\src\app\app.component.ts

```
import { MyUtil } from "../../../util/packages/core/src";
```

which get
error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../util/packages/core/src'

How to fix this error?

Angular version is 14.2.

Comment: usually if you take off one more more '../' or add one or more '../' to the path, you will eventually find it.

Comment: Which operation system do you use?

Comment: @Rick, I had tried taking off one more more '../' or adding one or more '../' to the path before I posted this question.

Comment: @Nikita Bardakov, Windows Home.